# Magento 2 downloadable product does not appear in my downloadable products when in grouped product

Tags: magento2

When i create grouped product in magento 2 with simple product and downloadable product (book and ebook) after making purchase link to download product is not showing up in My Downloadable Product.

Even after checking tables downloadable_link_purchased and downloadable_link_purchased_item tables  there aren't any entries in they are empty.

You can reproduce this error on magento 2

This bug has been logged with magento: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/7413

Is anyone able to let me know how i can debug this. How the checkout works in magento, just need some one to point me in the right direction.